# question regarding updating from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, 13.10, downloads

I now want to update my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04....when i start the update or upgrade, will it reinstall everything, like re-download the whole distro or will it download a few files needed for the update?

Comment: If a package really hasn't been updated, it won't be redownloaded. But most packages will be updated, and downloaded again. It would be almost equivalent to re-downloading the whole distro.

Comment: check this link out. Explains what to do. http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu This link that @K-Bear13 provided was the answer.